# How to change default format at created_at and updated_at value laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, timestamp, eloquent

I am new in Laravel. I am creating a application with laravel. When i creating a post then the values of "created_at" and 'updated_at" are look like this:

```
2014-06-26 04:07:31
2014-06-26 04:07:31
```

But i want this values without time look like this :

```
2014-06-26
2014-06-26
```

Only date without time.

Is it possible ???

Please help me.

My Post Model:

```
<?php

class Post extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('title', 'body', 'meta','reporter', 'slug', 'image','top');

    public static $rules = array(
        'title'=>'required|min:2',
        'body'=>'required|min:20',
        'reporter'=> 'required|min:2',
        'image'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif'
    );

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
    }

}
```

My Post Controller store:

```
public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Post::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = Input::get('title');
        $post->body = Input::get('body');
        $post->reporter = Input::get('reporter');
        $post->meta = Input::get('meta');
        $post->slug = Input::get('title');
        $post->top = Input::get('top');

        $image = Input::file('image');
        if ($image) {
            $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(250, 145)->save('public/images/postimages/'.$filename);
            $post->image = 'images/postimages/'.$filename;
        }


        $categories = Input::get('categories');

        $post->save();

        $post->categories()->sync($categories);

        return Redirect::route('admin.posts.index')
            ->with('message', 'Product Created');
    }

    return Redirect::back()
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In your `Post` model add two accessor methods like this:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Now every time you use these properties from your model to show a date these will be presented differently, just the date without the time, for example:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
echo $post->created_at; // only Y-m-d formatted date will be displayed
```

So you don't need to change the original type in the database. to change the `type` in your database you need to change it to `Date` from `Timestamp` and you need to do it from your migration (If your using at all) or directly into your database if you are not using migration. The `timestamps()` method adds these fields (using Migration) and to change these fields during the migration you need to remove the `timestamps()` method and use `date()` instead, for example:

```
$table->date('created_at');
$table->date('updated_at');
```

Comment: Working, but you shouldn't be changing the format inside your model. You should do it from inside your view : $post->created_at->format('Y-m-d'); You can also change the format globally for every dates by using the static method Carbon\Carbon::setToStringFormat('Y-m-d');

Comment: `Laravel` provides a convenient way to do it from model instead of using it in every view, nothing is bad here but there are other ways, for example: using a `view presenter` class.

Comment: using `public static $dates = ['updated_at', 'created_at'];` in your model will make these fields `Carbon` by default, so inside your `getXXXAttribute()` methods you only type `return $this->updated_at->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: Is is on a per-model basis.  I wonder if there a global (configuration-based) approach?

Comment: It's per model basis but if you have a parent model than which extends eloquent model then you can do that easily.

Answer (score 77):

```
{{ $post->created_at }}
```

will return '2014-06-26 04:07:31'

The solution is

```
{{ $post->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

Comment: Thanks. for providing one that works within Blade. Should've known an error wasn't thrown when using the property directly because of a __toString method.

Comment: This is formatting dates individually but the questioner asked for changing default format, not per individual blade usage.

Answer (score 13):

## Laravel 4.x and 5.0

To change the time in the database use:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps

Providing A Custom Timestamp Format

If you wish to customize the format of your timestamps, you may override the getDateFormat method in your model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected function getDateFormat()
    {
        return 'U';
    }

}
```

## Laravel 5.1+

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

If you need to customize the format of your timestamps, set the $dateFormat property on your model. This property determines how date attributes are stored in the database, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an array or JSON:

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}
```

Comment: You can also just set `protected $dateFormat = 'U';`

Comment: I think that only exists in newer editions of Laravel, but I'll update the answer to note that.

Comment: In Laravel 5.6 `$dateFormat` is public

Comment: @Daniel It looks like it is still protected to me: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.6/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L57 Can you point to where it is public?

Comment: @Loren https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade (`This getDateFormat method is now public instead of protected.`)

Comment: @Daniel Ah, got it, `$dateFormat` (the field), however is still protected and is the easiest thing to override for Laravel 5.1+ to change the date format (rather than overriding the `getDateFormat` method).

Answer (score 9):

You can also try like this.

```
Use Carbon\Carbon;


$created_at = "2014-06-26 04:07:31";

$date = Carbon::parse($created_at);

echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => "datetime:Y-m-d\TH:iPZ",
];
```

in your model class
or any format following this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is looking for a **simple** solution in Laravel 5.3:

1. Let default `timestamps()` be saved as is i.e. '2016-11-14 12:19:49'
2. In your views, format the field as below (or as required):

   ```
    date('F d, Y', strtotime($list->created_at))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Casting is the proper way to do this in Laravel 9+ and regardless of your front-end; blade, vue, react... the variables will be treated properly.

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'json' => 'object',
    'active' => 'boolean',
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Answer (score 1):

**In laravel 8 to 10**

When setting the

```
protected $timeStamps = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

This only affects when you `update` or `create`

but when you `get/fetch` from an eloquent
the format will always have a timestamp with timezone which is the default

sample:

```
2023-06-14T06:27:18.000000Z

// on your Model.php

use use DateTimeInterface;
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date): string
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Everytime you user Eloquent to query the `timestamps` if enabled will now have the `Y-m-d H:i:s` format

if you like it to be in effect to all model, Just create a `BaseModel` with the following `property` then Extend all your models

Read More at [Laravel 10 - Date Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

Answer (score 0):

In **laravel 6** the latest one can easily add in the "APP/user.php" model:

```
/**
 * The storage format of the model's date columns.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $dateFormat = 'U';
```

And in schema one can add

```
    $table->integer('created_at')->nullable();
    $table->integer('updated_at')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon\Carbon;

```
$targetDate =  "2014-06-26 04:07:31";
Carbon::parse($targetDate)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

For newers versions of laravel, you just need to declare it in your Model, like this:

```
class Your_class_name extends Model {

    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';

    ...


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just doing it directly in the blade file

```
$post->created_at->format('Y-m-d')
```

Answer (score -1):

**LARAVEL 9^**

in your model add this.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];

protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $dates)
{
    //return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dates)->diffForHumans();
    OR
    //return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dates)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```