# Laravel cast for created_at date field not being applied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a created_at column in my user model that I would like to format differently when accessing it in my blade template, so it is more readable. It seems like the best way to go about this is to use a cast.

I created a cast like so:

```
     protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'created_at'  => 'm-d-y',
    ];
```

... in my controller, I am getting a User and then doing:

```
dd($member->toArray());
```

Now, when getting a user record and doing `$user->toArray()` the created_at column is still in the original uncasted format, it seems the cast isn't being used at all, any idea why this is?

Comment: I don't think `m-d-y` is valid in `$casts`, since casting it for setting type, like `string`, `int`, `datetime`, etc, not for formatting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441395/how-to-change-default-format-at-created-at-and-updated-at-value-laravel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a format for date columns using following snippet(in model):

```
protected $dateFormat = 'm-d-Y';
```

In case of updating individual timestamp fields use the following.

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at'  => 'date:m-d-Y',
    // 'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:00',
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Getting this error: `The separation symbol could not be found Trailing data`

Comment: Things should works. However, I have updated the answer for individuals dates format. Try that one

Comment: You will either need to use a $dateFormat or $cast solution. comment the $dateFormat line and add $cast array.

Comment: Uncommenting the $dateFormat variable and changing the cast created_at value, did the trick. I wonder why the $dateFormat method didn't work and I was forced to use $cast?

Comment: I will check this issue and let you know.