# Wrong date and time showed

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-9

With this line:

```
<td><% district.created_at %></td>
```

I'm getting this output:

```
2022-08-06T09:14:58.000000Z
```

It should be like this:

```
2022-08-06 09:14:58
```

The correct printout is from Laravel 5.3 and the wrong from Laravel 9.
What could be the problem and how to correct?

Comment: Please clarify - is the problem that you are getting two different dates, or that the format is different?

Comment: Sorry, it's the format that's different. Adjusted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default format at created\_at and updated\_at value laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441395/how-to-change-default-format-at-created-at-and-updated-at-value-laravel)

Comment: Perhaps there is an answer in that possible dup?

Comment: Ken Y-N
 No, as the printout is in the form <% district.created_at %> in the blade file (angularjs) so those tips do not apply. The thing is that it works fine in Laravel 5.3 but not in my upgraded Laravel 9

Comment: I have looked around and found out that this is some kind of ASP statement. So it looks like it's a kins of script "Scripts surrounded by <% and %> are executed on the server". But I don't know how this works.

Answer (score 0):

why not try with a date and day format like YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS

```
$mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
echo $mytime->toDateTimeString();
```

Comment: Well, not that simple. The statement <td><% district.created_at %></td> is angularjs and I don't know how to address the format. It has to do with the difference between Laravel 5.3 (shows correct format) and Laravel 9 (wrong format).